# How to create custom dialog with FXML in JavaFX?

Tags: java, graphics, javafx

How to create custom dialog with FXML in JavaFX?

In samples over the Net I see mostly something like this

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
   Parent root =
      FXMLLoader.load(
         getClass().getResource( getClass().getSimpleName() + ".fxml" ));
   Scene scene = new Scene(root);
```

i.e. `FXML` is loaded from within application `start()` and builds root node.

But what if I extend Stage? Where to load from FXML? In constructor? Or in `initStyle()`? Or in some other method?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the below code in your main Class :

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));
Parent root = (Parent)loader.load();

//Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml"));        
Scene scene = new Scene(root);        
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();

SampleController controller = (SampleController)loader.getController();
controller.setStageAndSetupListeners(stage);
```

After this in SampleController Make a function setStageAndSetupListeners(), which will accept your stage and now you use it easily.

Comment: Why are so many lines? Is it possible to design dialog so that it can be called with 1-2 lines of code?

Comment: You have to get Loader so that you can use stage and pass on another fxml for inter communication between main Dialog to sub Dialog.

Comment: `Parent root = (Parent)loader.load();` may be written `Parent root = loader.<Parent>load();`

Comment: How to get result from dialog back to parent controller?